# Monitoring Linux logs for an ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-security-group, linux-security-module, amazon-guardduty

How do I monitor Linux logs for an ec2 instance? I was thinking of using guard duty but came to know that it doesn't scan the os logs. How do I ensure that if any kind of attack/security threat happens into the ec2 instance I get notified immediately?

Comment: I think you'll have difficulty finding something that can detect "any kind of attack/security threat" -- that's a very big ask. There would also be multiple logs (eg operating system, web server, application logs). You could possibly find a third-party security product that can scan such logs.

Comment: Any suggestion on any such security product?